# kill -9 backgrounded job also kills bash

Tags: bash, kill, background-process

```
sleep 1 & kill -9 $?
```

The above will kill either (most likely) the **bash** shell or the current terminal window.

Why is that?

---

NOTE: `sleep 1 & kill $?` does not kill the shell/terminal.

Just to be sure that I don't run something different what I think, have some race condition, etc., the following also produces the same effect:

```
/bin/sleep 2 & pid=$?; sleep 1; kill -9 $pid
```

GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$?` is the exit status of the last command. Starting a background command always succeeds, so in `… & do_something_with $?`, the value of `$?` is 0. You're running `kill -9 0`.

The PID passed to the `kill` shell command is passed down to the underlying system call. Shell manuals don't document that it can be something other than a PID, but [the system call manual does](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html). If the PID is 0, this means all processes in the current [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). (And -1 means every process except PID 1, and another negative value means every process in the designated process group.) A shell running in a terminal is in its own process group (unless you go through substantial hoops or there are subshells which are not in a background job), so `kill -9 0` is equivalent to `kill -9 $$`: it kills the shell process.

Any background process, such as the `sleep` command, keeps running. It did not receive a signal and the shell didn't even get a chance to send one. The death of the terminal will generally not affect it either, although some programs may error out if they try to write to a closed terminal (which of course `sleep` won't do).

`kill 0` sends the TERM signal, which the shell ignores. `kill -9 0` sends the KILL signal, which cannot be ignored.

---

If you meant to kill the most recent background process, that's `$!`.

Comment: `bash`'s manual may not document it but `zsh`'s does (*Many systems will allow process IDs to be negative to kill a process group or zero to kill the current process group*). It doesn't document `kill -- -1` though. ksh93 does document `-number` for process groups (in `kill --man`) but not 0 nor -1. mksh does mention that you can kill process groups, but not that you  need it to be negative number. All document that it can be a job spec. I agree the documentation could be improved on that front in a lot of them.